# error 1001. the specified service already exists

Tags: service, windows-services, installation

I am writing a C# windows service and I was able to install and uninstall in Visual Studio fine, then not sure what I did in the code and messed things up. Now when I try to install, I get the error 1001:

```
The specified service already exists.
```

But when I try an uninstall, it gives me:

```
Another program is being installed. Please wait until that installation is complete, and then try installing this software again.
```

I do see my service still listed in the Services.  What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

sc delete [service name] is what works for me.  Be sure to open cmd as a administrator otherwise you will get access denied error.

Comment: OMG Thanks! One small note, if your service name has spaces in it, you have to use sc delete "My service name"